# how I can inssert valuees in the dict in python using for loop

Tags: python

```
from random import *
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import FCM as FCM
from collections import defaultdict

ii=Image.open("dataset/image11.jpg").convert("L")
data = list(ii.getdata())

#print(aa)
person = {}
N=[]
all={}

for j in range(8):
    for i in range(4):
        N.append(randint(min(data),max(data)))
    
    person['cluster'] = N
    person['obj']=FCM.objfunc(FCM.rlistes(data,person['cluster']),person['cluster'])
    all[j]=person
    N.clear()
    person.clear()
print(all)
```

How I can add all values of person dictionary in the all dictionary because when I run the code the result will be as
{0: {}, 1: {}, 2: {}, 3: {}, 4: {}, 5: {}, 6: {}, 7: {}}
I need to insert all values of person in all dictionary

Answer (score 1):

To solve this you can insert values into the 'person' dictionary in the following code using a for loop by replacing with these lines:

```
for j in range(8):
for i in range(4):
    N.append(randint(min(data),max(data)))

person['cluster'] = N
person['obj']=FCM.objfunc(FCM.rlistes(data,person['cluster']),person['cluster'])
all[j]=person
N.clear()
person.clear()
```

with

```
for j in range(8):
N = [randint(min(data),max(data)) for i in range(4)]

person = {
    'cluster': N,
    'obj': FCM.objfunc(FCM.rlistes(data, N), N)
}

all[j] = person
```

this way we use a list to create the list 'N' with 4 random integers from the range of 'data'. Then we create a new 'person' dict with keys 'cluster' and 'obj' and the values of the result of the 'objfunc()'. Finally, we insert the 'person' dictionary into the 'all' dictionary using the loop index 'j'.

Let me know if this worked for you :D